# How to transform date string in Druid

Tags: druid

I am adding a Druid ingestion spec and one my fields called maturityDate is a string in the format "dd/MM/yyyy". Sample data: 5/01/2023

I am using Druid UI console and in the Transform phase, adding the following expression:

timestamp("maturityDate", "dd/MM/yyyy")

But as I apply this transform, Druid results in an error. Can someone suggest the right way of converting a string to long (millis since epoch) in Druid?

Comment: Please try: `timestamp_parse("maturityDate", "dd/MM/yyyy")`

Comment: Thanks @58k723f1. But when I try the above, I get: Error: Unknown exception

org.apache.calcite.runtime.CalciteContextException: From line 7, column 38 to line 7, column 49: Column 'dd/MM/yyyy' not found in any table

Comment: I have some bad experience with quotes. When using double quotes `"`, druid assumes that is a column or data source or so. Please try playing around with using single quotes `'`

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following way:

```
TIME_PARSE('05/01/2023', 'dd/MM/yyyy')
```

Additional short tips for druid usage:

- be aware between `"` and `'` usages, because it's two different options;
- according to [druid docs](https://druid.apache.org/docs/latest/querying/sql-metadata-tables.html): druid metadata tables (such as "sys") doesn't support almost all aggregations

> *INFORMATION_SCHEMA tables do not currently support Druid-specific functions like TIME_PARSE*